# ipad suffix not working for images

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I'm making a universal app and trying to get the background with the correct resolution loaded for each device. I have 4 different images for the 4 different cases, but the ~ipad suffix is not working. I am working on the iOS Simulator and this is what happens:

iPhone: loads "bg_one.jpg"

iPhone Retina: loads "bg_one@2x.jpg"

iPad: loads "bg_one.jpg"

iPad Retina: loads "bg_one@2x.jpg"

I have a "bg_one~ipad.jpg" and a "bg_one@2x~ipad.jpg" but they never get used. What could be wrong?

UPDATE:

I would still like a solution to this problem, but I'll share the work around that I am using in the meantime:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
     bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_main.jpg"];
else bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_main~ipad.jpg"];
```

Comment: What makes you think they're not being used?  Also you know that you just need to reference the image as "bg_one" and that the compiler will automatically find the @2x, ~ipad, and @2x~ipad suffixes, right?  If you specifically request "bg_one~ipad", it actually won't work.  It will look for "bg_one~ipad~ipad", which of couse doesn't exist.

Comment: Because both ~ipad images are red and the non ~ipad images are blue. Also, the loaded images are two small on the ipad screens. And yes, I call the image without any suffix.

Comment: Okay, that's a good reason to think they're not being used ;)  Just wanted to double check.  Did you see my edited comment?  Just another double-check before I really start wondering what's going on here :)

Comment: Yes I did. like I said, I call the image with no suffixes - if that were the problem the 2x one wouldn't load either

Comment: Is it possible your deployment target is set to less than 4.0?  The ability to load iPad-specific resources was only introduced in iOS 4.0, so if you are targeting a lower version this would not work.

Comment: It was set to 4.0. I changed it to 5.1 just to be sure, but nothing changed

Comment: You are 100% sure that you have all images included in your target? There are a few of these reports on SO - I've responded to a few - and its maddening for everyone. In any case, you are loading these using "imageNamed:@"bg_one", or entering that name in IB. I have a suggestion - create a new single view demo iOS app, put an imageView in the single view, name it "bg_one", and add the four images to this project. Run it on retina/non-retina simulators, and see if it works or not. This well may be some really oddball problem in the frameworks. There are at least 3 other people having problems.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check for sure that the images are included in my target, but I'm putting them in the same place as my other images, and I've never had a problem with any of them before. I can try to run the test, but I don't know much about ios coding outside of Cocos2d - which method of what class should I load the bg in?

Comment: You need to make sure they're included in your project; just putting them in the same directory won't work.